# Duplicate log entries with Google Cloud Stackdriver logging of Python code on Kubernetes Engine

Tags: python, logging, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, python-logging

I have a simple Python app running in a container on Google Kubernetes Engine. I am trying to connect the standard Python logging to Google Stackdriver logging [using this guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python). I have almost succeeded, but I am getting duplicate log entries with one always at the 'error' level...

---

Screenshot of Stackdriver logs showing duplicate entries

[image: Screenshot of Stackdriver logs showing duplicate entries]

This is my python code that set's up the logging according to the above guide:

```
import webapp2
from paste import httpserver
import rpc

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
import google.cloud.logging
# Instantiates a client
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
# Connects the logger to the root logging handler; by default this captures
# all logs at INFO level and higher
client.setup_logging()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/rpc/([A-Za-z]+)', rpc.RpcHandler),], debug=True)
httpserver.serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port='80')
```

Here's the code that triggers the logs from the screenshot:

```
import logging

logging.info("INFO Entering PostEchoPost...")
logging.warning("WARNING Entering PostEchoPost...")
logging.error("ERROR Entering PostEchoPost...")
logging.critical("CRITICAL Entering PostEchoPost...")
```

Here is the full Stackdriver log, expanded from the screenshot, with an incorrectly interpreted ERROR level:

```
{
 insertId:  "1mk4fkaga4m63w1"  
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "gke-alg-microservice-default-pool-xxxxxxxxxx-ttnz"   
  container.googleapis.com/namespace_name:  "default"   
  container.googleapis.com/pod_name:  "esp-alg-xxxxxxxxxx-xj2p2"   
  container.googleapis.com/stream:  "stderr"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/projectname/logs/algorithm"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-01-03T12:18:22.479058645Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   cluster_name:  "alg-microservice"    
   container_name:  "alg"    
   instance_id:  "703849119xxxxxxxxxx"   
   namespace_id:  "default"    
   pod_id:  "esp-alg-xxxxxxxxxx-xj2p2"    
   project_id:  "projectname"    
   zone:  "europe-west1-b"    
  }
  type:  "container"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "INFO Entering PostEchoPost...
"  
 timestamp:  "2018-01-03T12:18:20Z"  
}
```

Here is the the full Stackdriver log, expanded from the screenshot, with a correctly interpreted INFO level:

```
{
 insertId:  "1mk4fkaga4m63w0"  
 jsonPayload: {
  message:  "INFO Entering PostEchoPost..."   
  thread:  140348659595008   
 }
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "gke-alg-microservi-default-pool-xxxxxxxxxx-ttnz"   
  container.googleapis.com/namespace_name:  "default"   
  container.googleapis.com/pod_name:  "esp-alg-xxxxxxxxxx-xj2p2"   
  container.googleapis.com/stream:  "stderr"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/projectname/logs/algorithm"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-01-03T12:18:22.479058645Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   cluster_name:  "alg-microservice"    
   container_name:  "alg"    
   instance_id:  "703849119xxxxxxxxxx"    
   namespace_id:  "default"    
   pod_id:  "esp-alg-xxxxxxxxxx-xj2p2"    
   project_id:  "projectname"    
   zone:  "europe-west1-b"    
  }
  type:  "container"   
 }
 severity:  "INFO"  
 timestamp:  "2018-01-03T12:18:20.260099887Z"  
}
```

So, this entry might be the key:

```
container.googleapis.com/stream:  "stderr"
```

It looks like in addition to my logging set-up working, all logs from the container are being send to stderr in the container, and I believe that by default, at least on Kubernetes Container Engine, all stdout/stderr are picked up by Google Stackdriver via FluentD... Having said that, I'm out of my depth at this point.

Any ideas why I am getting these duplicate entries?

Comment: The linked-to document states that: "Note: Logs written to stdout and stderr are automatically sent to Stackdriver Logging for you, without needing to use Stackdriver Logging library for Python."
This is implies that the information you need is already there. As the note text indicates, you don't need to use the Stackdriver Logging library, and generate extra logs with duplicated information.

Comment: @George if only the default logging to Cloud Logging didn't write out log levels wrong, like WARN as ERROR.

Comment: I have the same issue. I used this guide linked below to correctly set the severity of the messages, but I too get a set of duplicates with severity one level higher:
https://medium.com/retailmenot-engineering/formatting-python-logs-for-stackdriver-5a5ddd80761c

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by overwriting the `handlers` property on my root logger immediately after calling the `setup_logging` method

```
import logging
from google.cloud import logging as gcp_logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler, ContainerEngineHandler, AppEngineHandler

logging_client = gcp_logging.Client()
logging_client.setup_logging(log_level=logging.INFO)
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
# use the GCP handler ONLY in order to prevent logs from getting written to STDERR
root_logger.handlers = [handler
                        for handler in root_logger.handlers
                        if isinstance(handler, (CloudLoggingHandler, ContainerEngineHandler, AppEngineHandler))]
```

To elaborate on this a bit, the `client.setup_logging` method sets up *2 handlers*, a normal `logging.StreamHandler` and also a GCP-specific handler. So, logs will go to both stderr and Cloud Logging. You need to remove the stream handler from the handlers list to prevent the duplication.

EDIT: 
I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues/38) with Google to add an argument to to make this less hacky.

Comment: Just a heads up for others experiencing a similar issue with Google Cloud Functions rather than k8s. Removing the streaming handler appears to result in no logs at all.

Comment: Greetings from 2022! Now that v3 is out, on supported environments (including GKE) google-cloud-logging uses GCP's structured logging feature. The above solution worked brilliantly for me once I realised I had to import `google.cloud.logging.handlers.StructuredLogHandler` and add that to the tuple of GCP handler classes.

(it's odd, the underlying problem is supposed to be fixed! But `setup_logging` was definitely leaving a redundant StreamHandler attached to the root logger for me.)

Answer (score 6):

Writing in 2022, shortly after v3.0.0 of `google-cloud-logging` was released, and this issue cropped up for me too (albeit almost certainly for a different reason).

#### Debugging

The most useful thing I did on the way to debugging it was stick the following in my code:

```py
import logging
...
root_logger = logging.getLogger()  # no arguments = return the root logger
print(root_logger.handlers, flush=True)  # tell me what handlers are attached
...
```

If you're getting duplicate logs, it seems certain that it's because you've got multiple handlers attached to your logger, and Stackdriver is catching logs from both of them! To be fair, that is Stackdriver's job; it's just a pity that `google-cloud-logging` can't sort this out by default.

The good news is that Stackdriver will also catch the `print` statement (which goes to the STDOUT stream). In my case, the following list of handlers was logged: `[<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>, <StructuredLogHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]`. So: two handlers were attached to the root logger.

#### Fixing it

You might be able to find that your code is attaching the handler somewhere else, and simply remove that part. But it may instead be the case that e.g. a dependency is setting up the extra handler, something I wrestled with.

I used a solution based on [the answer written by Andy Carlson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602361/9044370). Keeping it general/extensible:

```py
import google.cloud.logging
import logging

def is_cloud_handler(handler: logging.Handler) -> bool:
    """
    is_cloud_handler

    Returns True or False depending on whether the input is a
    google-cloud-logging handler class

    """
    accepted_handlers = (
        google.cloud.logging.handlers.StructuredLogHandler,
        google.cloud.logging.handlers.CloudLoggingHandler,
        google.cloud.logging.handlers.ContainerEngineHandler,
        google.cloud.logging.handlers.AppEngineHandler,
    )
    return isinstance(handler, accepted_handlers)


def set_up_logging():
    # here we assume you'll be using the basic logging methods
    # logging.info, logging.warn etc. which invoke the root logger
    client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    client.setup_logging()

    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.handlers = [h for h in root_logger.handlers if is_cloud_handler(h)]
```

#### More context

*For those who find this solution confusing*

In Python there is a separation between 'loggers' and 'handlers': loggers generate logs, and handlers decide what happens to them. Thus, you can attach multiple handlers to the same logger (in case you want multiple things to happen to the logs from that logger).

The `google-cloud-logging` library suggests that you run its `setup_logging` method and then just use the basic logging methods of the built in `logging` library to create your logs. These are: `logging.debug`, `logging.info`, `logging.warning`, `logging.error`, and `logging.critical` (in escalating order of urgency).

All `logging.Logger` instances have the same methods, including a special `Logger` instance called the root logger. If you look at [the source code for the basic logging methods](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2142), they simply call these methods on this root logger.

It's possible to set up specific `Logger`s, which is standard practice to demarcate logs generated by different areas of an application (rather than sending everything via the root logger). This is done using `logging.getLogger("name-of-logger")`. However, `logging.getLogger()` with no argument returns the root logger.

Meanwhile, the purpose of the `google.cloud.logging.Client.setup_logging` method is to *attach a special log handler to the root logger*. Thus, logs created using `logging.info` etc. will be handled by a `google-cloud-logging` handler. **But** you have to make sure no other handlers are also attached to the root logger.

Fortunately, `Logger`s have a property, `.handlers`, which is a list of attached log handlers. In this solution we just edit that list to ensure we have just one handler.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is in the way how logging client initializes root logger

```py
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(log_level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

it adds default stream handler in addition to Stackdriver handler.
My workaround for now is to initialize appropriate Stackdriver handler manually:

```py
            # this basically manually sets logger compatible with GKE/fluentd
            # as LoggingClient automatically add another StreamHandler - so 
            # log records are duplicated
            from google.cloud.logging.handlers import ContainerEngineHandler
            formatter = logging.Formatter("%(message)s")
            handler = ContainerEngineHandler(stream=sys.stderr)
            handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            handler.setLevel(level)
            root = logging.getLogger()
            root.addHandler(handler)
            root.setLevel(level)
```