# How to redirect abseil logging messages to stackdriver using google.cloud.logging without having duplicate with wrong "label"?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, abseil

I am using `AI Platform training` to run ML training job using `python` `3.7.6`. I am using the abseil module for logging messages with `absl-py` `0.9.0`. I look at the instruction on how to direct python logging messages to stackdriver [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python) [medium article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/python-and-stackdriver-logging-2ade460c90e3). I am using `google-cloud-logging` `1.15.0`. I did some very basic code to understand the issue with my configuration.

```
from absl import logging
from absl import flags
from absl import app
import logging as logger
import google.cloud.logging

import sys
import os

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

def main(argv):

    logging.get_absl_handler().python_handler.stream = sys.stdout

    # Instantiates a client
    client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

    # Connects the logger to the root logging handler; by default this captures
    # all logs at INFO level and higher
    client.setup_logging()

    fmt = "[%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s"
    formatter = logger.Formatter(fmt)
    logging.get_absl_handler().setFormatter(formatter)

    # set level of verbosity
    logging.set_verbosity(logging.DEBUG)

    print(' 0 print --- ')
    logging.info(' 1 logging:')
    logging.info(' 2 logging:')

    print(' 3 print --- ')
    logging.debug(' 4 logging-test-debug')
    logging.info(' 5 logging-test-info')
    logging.warning(' 6 logging-test-warning')
    logging.error(' 7 logging test-error')
    print(' 8 print --- ')
    print(' 9 print --- ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)
```

First abseil send all logs to the stderr. Note sure if this is expected or not. In the screenshot below we see:

1. print messages using `print` are display (later in  the logfile from `Stackdriver`)
2. Abseil logging messages appear 2 times. One with the right label in stack driver (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING or ERROR) and one more time with the special formatting `[%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s` but always with the ERROR label in `Stackdriver`.
3. When I run the code locally I don't see duplicate.

[image: screenshot of the output in GCP stackdriver]

Any idea how to have this setup properly to see the logging messages (using abseil) once with the proper "label" in `Stackdriver` ?

----- EDIT --------

1. I am seeing the issue locally and not only when running on `GCP`.
2. The duplicate log messages appear when I add this line: `client.setup_logging()`. Before, I have no duplicate and all log messages are in the stdout stream
3. If I look at the logger `logger.root.manager.loggerDict.keys()`, I see a lot of them:

> ```
> dict_keys(['absl', 'google.auth.transport._http_client', 'google.auth.transport', 'google.auth', 'google','google.auth._default', 'grpc._cython.cygrpc', 'grpc._cython', 'grpc', 'google.api_core.retry', 'google.api_core', 'google.auth.transport._mtls_helper', 'google.auth.transport.grpc', 'urllib3.util.retry', 'urllib3.util', 'urllib3', 'urllib3.connection', 'urllib3.response', 'urllib3.connectionpool', 'urllib3.poolmanager', 'urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl', 'urllib3.contrib', 'socks', 'requests', 'google.auth.transport.requests', 'grpc._common', 'grpc._channel', 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.transports.background_thread', 'google.cloud.logging.handlers.transports', 'google.cloud.logging.handlers', 'google.cloud.logging', 'google.cloud', 'google_auth_httplib2'])
> ```

4. If I look at:

> ```
> root_logger = logger.getLogger()
>
> for handler in root_logger.handlers:
>     print("handler ", handler)
> ```

I see:

```
handler  <ABSLHandler (NOTSET)>
handler  <CloudLoggingHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>
handler  <StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>
```

and we can see that the stream is stderr and not stdout. I didn''t managed to change it.

I saw this discussion [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078051/duplicate-log-entries-with-google-cloud-stackdriver-logging-of-python-code-on-ku) and I tried the last solution by @Andy Carlson but then all my logging message are gone.

Comment: 1- what is the content of the duplicate logs?

2- Could you test with the [standard python library](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#using_the_python_root_logger) in the AI Platform training and localy to isolate the issue?

Comment: @KhalidK it seems that everything that goes to logger got duplicated. If I run the same pice of code "client.setup_logging()" then everytihng work fine. Or logging output are see oncee and only in the stdout stream. So "client.setup_logging()" duplicate logging messages that then will appear in both stdout and stderr.

Comment: You mean logs are not duplicated when you run the code without the "client.setup_logging()". I recommend to open a [bug](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues)

Comment: Just did it [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues/40). The situation start to be even more confusion when importing Tensorflow and Transformers libs.I guess this is clashes betweem logging, absl.logging and google.cloud.logging. I guess my issue is that I don't really get how they aare orking and suppose to interact between each other.