# Duplicate log entries google cloud logging on stackdriver in google cloud function using python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to attach a logging handler to the Python root logger in my cloud function. I am using below code :

```
    import logging
    import os
    import google.cloud.logging
    from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler, setup_logging
    
    logLabels = {'ServerName' : os.uname().nodename}
    logging_client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    handler = CloudLoggingHandler(logging_client,name='my-test-cf',labels=logLabels)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    setup_logging(handler, excluded_loggers=('google.cloud', 'google.auth', 'google_auth_httplib2'))
    logging.info(f"Starting Execution of My Test CF")
```

Result is duplicate log entries one with info and other with error

1. info -> Starting Execution of My Test CF
2. error -> Starting Execution of My Test CF

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First you need to setup the logging to sent all log intries to Cloud Logging by attaching the Cloud Logging handler to the Python Root logger.

```
import google.cloud.logging
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.get_default_handler()
client.setup_logging()
```

Once the handler is attached, any logs (by default `INFO`) which are emitted in you application will be sent to Logging.

```
import logging
logging.info(f"Starting Execution of My Test CF")
```

Comment: Logs are being sent to Logging. Problem is that it make duplicate entries.

Comment: Put 'import logging' statement after setting up logging handler

Comment: I used below code def start_process(request):
  import google.cloud.logging
  client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
  client.get_default_handler()
  client.setup_logging()

  import logging
  logging.info(f"Starting Execution of My Test CF") but result is duplicate entries            D 2020-08-05T06:50:27.166180883Z Function execution started 
I 2020-08-05T06:50:28.167Z  Starting Execution of My Test CF 
E 2020-08-05T06:50:28.167Z Starting Execution of My Test CF
D 2020-08-05T06:50:28.168703870Z Function execution took 1003 ms, finished with status code: 200

Comment: The duplicate entries can be from    1. Normal app logging into stdout.          2. Stackdriver loggings                         Use filter on stackdriver with selecting appropriate app

Comment: When I am removing handler code then it does not result duplicate entries. like below import logging
logging.info(f"Starting Execution of My Test CF") then result is 2020-08-05 00:08:13.256 PDT Starting Execution of My Test CF

Comment: Do you want to share screenshot of duplicate entries.

Comment: sure. I added screen-print of stackdriver log in question.

Comment: I think, Google has changed the logging implementation in Cloud Function.
No need to setup anything. 
just `import logging` and it will work.

Comment: I understand that the code used, as outlined by the google public documentation to [connect Cloud Logging and the Python native logging module](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#connecting_the_library_to_python_logging), is causing duplicate entries in your Cloud Functions logs. It is also suspected that Cloud Functions automatically integrates Cloud Logging with the Python logging module. As of now I am in the process of verifying if this is the case with our Cloud Functions specialists. Please expect a update by August 9 or as soon as there are details made available.

Comment: It seems that a similar issue was found on another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078051/duplicate-log-entries-with-google-cloud-stackdriver-logging-of-python-code-on-ku/58655297#58655297). Please attempt the workarounds provided here and see if the issue persists for the time being. I will provide a update here as soon as details are made available from our specialists.

Comment: It seems that this issue is indeed reproducible and this functionality is not mentioned particularly anywhere on our public documentation. Therefore it is recommended that this issue should be investigated further. Firstly a possible workaround for this issue would be to utilize the [Cloud Logging client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#using_the_logging_api) so as to write logs to Cloud Logging. Secondly, please submit a new [Public Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) on Public Issue Tracker so that we may investigate this issue further.