# Log to Cloud Logging with correct severity from Cloud Run Job and package used in the job

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

**What we are trying**: 
We are trying to Run a Cloud Run Job that does some computation and also uses one our custom package to do the computation. The cloud run job is using **google-cloud-logging** and python's default logging package as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#connecting_the_library_to_python_logging). The custom python package also logs its data (only logger is defined as suggested [here](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/python-logging-basics/#:%7E:text=Logging%20from%20Modules)).

**Simple illustration:**

```
from google.cloud import logging as gcp_logging
import logging
import os
import google.auth
from our_package import do_something

def log_test_function():
    SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
    try:
        function_logger_name = os.getenv("FUNCTION_LOGGER_NAME")

        logging_client = gcp_logging.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)
        logging.basicConfig()
        logger = logging.getLogger(function_logger_name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logging_client.setup_logging(log_level=logging.INFO)

        logger.critical("Critical Log TEST")
        logger.error("Error Log TEST")
        logger.info("Info Log TEST")
        logger.debug("Debug Log TEST")

        result = do_something()
        logger.info(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)    # just to test how print works

    return "Returned"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = log_test_function()
    print(result)
```

**Cloud Run Job Logs**
[image: Cloud Run Job Logs]

The *Blue Box* indicates logs from custom package 
The *Black Box* indicates logs from Cloud Run Job 
The Cloud Logging is not able to identify the severity of logs. It parses every log entry as default level.

But if I run same code in Cloud Function, it seems to work as expected (i.e. severity level of logs from cloud function and custom package is respected) as shown in image below.

**Cloud Function Logs**
[image: Cloud Function Logs]

Both are serverless architecture than why does it works in Cloud Function but not in Cloud Run.

**What we want to do:**
We want to log every message from Cloud Run Job and custom package to Cloud Logging with correct severity.

We would appreciate your help guys!

---

**Edit 1** 
Following Google Cloud Python library commiters [solution](https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues/663). Almost solved the problem. Following is the modified code.

```
from google.cloud import logging as gcp_logging
import logging
import os
import google.auth
from our_package import do_something
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers import setup_logging
from google.cloud.logging_v2.resource import Resource
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers._monitored_resources import retrieve_metadata_server, _REGION_ID, _PROJECT_NAME

def log_test_function():
    SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    region = retrieve_metadata_server(_REGION_ID)
    project = retrieve_metadata_server(_PROJECT_NAME)
    try:
        function_logger_name = os.getenv("FUNCTION_LOGGER_NAME")

        # build a manual resource object
        cr_job_resource = Resource(
            type="cloud_run_job",
            labels={
                "job_name": os.environ.get('CLOUD_RUN_JOB', 'unknownJobId'),
                "location": region.split("/")[-1] if region else "",
                "project_id": project
            }
        )

        logging_client = gcp_logging.Client()
        gcloud_logging_handler = CloudLoggingHandler(logging_client, resource=cr_job_resource)
        setup_logging(gcloud_logging_handler, log_level=logging.INFO)

        logging.basicConfig()
        logger = logging.getLogger(function_logger_name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        logger.critical("Critical Log TEST")
        logger.error("Error Log TEST")
        logger.warning("Warning Log TEST")
        logger.info("Info Log TEST")
        logger.debug("Debug Log TEST")

        result = do_something()
        logger.info(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)    # just to test how print works

    return "Returned"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = log_test_function()
    print(result)
```

Now the every log is logged twice one severity sensitive log other severity insensitive logs at "default" level as shown below.
[image: Logs]

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions get your code, wrap it in a webserver, build a container and deploy it.

With Cloud Run, you only build and deploy the container.

That means, Cloud Functions webserver wrapper do something more that you do: it initialize correctly the logger in Python.

Have a look to that [doc page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python), you should solve your issue with it

---

**EDIT 1**

I took the exact example and I added it in my flask server like that

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

import google.cloud.logging

# Instantiates a client
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

# Retrieves a Cloud Logging handler based on the environment
# you're running in and integrates the handler with the
# Python logging module. By default this captures all logs
# at INFO level and higher
client.setup_logging()
# [END logging_handler_setup]

# [START logging_handler_usage]
# Imports Python standard library logging
import logging

@app.route('/')
def call_function():
    # The data to log
    text = "Hello, world!"

    # Emits the data using the standard logging module
    logging.warning(text)
    # [END logging_handler_usage]

    print("Logged: {}".format(text))
    return text


# For local execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT',8080)))
```

A rough copy of [that sample](https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/blob/77e621cb85b726a801227da85c31319f25969d19/samples/snippets/handler.py).

And the result is correct. A `Logged` entry with the default level (the print), and my `Hello world` in warning status (the logging.warning)

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to the help of the Google Cloud Python library commiters, I got a solution to my [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues/663). By waiting the native integration in the library.

Here my new code for Cloud Run Jobs this time

```
import google.cloud.logging
from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers import setup_logging
from google.cloud.logging_v2.resource import Resource
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers._monitored_resources import retrieve_metadata_server, _REGION_ID, _PROJECT_NAME
import os

# find metadata about the execution environment
region = retrieve_metadata_server(_REGION_ID)
project = retrieve_metadata_server(_PROJECT_NAME)

# build a manual resource object
cr_job_resource = Resource(
    type = "cloud_run_job",
    labels = {
        "job_name": os.environ.get('CLOUD_RUN_JOB', 'unknownJobId'),
        "location":  region.split("/")[-1] if region else "",
        "project_id": project
    }
)

# configure handling using CloudLoggingHandler with custom resource
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client, resource=cr_job_resource)
setup_logging(handler)

import logging

def call_function():
    # The data to log
    text = "Hello, world!"

    # Emits the data using the standard logging module
    logging.warning(text)
    # [END logging_handler_usage]

    print("Logged: {}".format(text))
    return text


# For local execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_function()
```

And the result works great:

- `Logged: ....` entry is the simple "Print" to the stdout. Standard level
- Warning entry as expected
  [image]

Comment: thank you for your response. Sorry, but I didn't get exactly what you are trying to say. I have followed the docs but still get the same result as shown in the image above for Cloud Run Job. Perhaps my code is a slight modification of the docs code. I don't see any problem how logger is initialized in the above code.

Comment: I have spent long enough on this problem, but with no success :/ I would appreciate your help!

Comment: I updated my answer. Nothing special, only a copy-paste of the doc. I didn't test with jobs, but it should be the same.

Comment: I have tried your solution as well, it does not work inside Cloud Run Job. But it works in Cloud Function.

Comment: indeed, doesn't work with jobs. let me search...

Comment: Spotted. In fact it works, but the label type of the logs is not correct, and so you don't find it related to your Cloud Run jobs run. But, have a look to your log entries in the whole Cloud Logging, you will find it! I will report the issue to the Google Cloud PM

Comment: Yes, I guess we can't find it under Cloud Run Job because it is getting allocated under Google Compute Engine (created by cloud run job) i.e. type=gce_instance instead of type=cloud_run_job. To summarize, logs are getting logged for cloud run job (severity insensitive logs) as well as Compute engine (severity sensitive logs). Thanks Guillaume!

Comment: Could you please leave the link to the issue here so that we can keep a track of the progress. Thank you.

Comment: It's the same issue in Golang. Issue Python: https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues/663

Comment: Have a look to the answer. It's interesting. I didn't test, but it sounds a good home made solution by waiting the final integration in the library.

Comment: I just tested and the code in the Gihub comment works perfectly!

Comment: I tried the solution from the Github comment. I am getting double entry for each log, one  severity sensitive log (which is required) other severity insensitive logs at "default" level (like before). @guillaume you only got severity sensitive logs?

Comment: I have updated my the post. I have tried some other configuration as well (eg. adding cloud logging handler explicitly to logger, etc.) but still same result.

Comment: import Logging AFTER the configuration of the logger

Comment: Somehow I have reached my quota limit :/ (Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Job run requests' and limit 'Job run requests per minute per region'). I'll try your suggestion once quota gets reset. Thanks

Comment: Hi I resolved my quota problem and I tried importing logging after configuring the logger as suggested, but still I get double logs :/

Answer (score 0):

you might want to get rid of loggers you don't need. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602361/13161301