# cloud run service log's summary is not textpayload

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to log within a cloud run service and all log summaries show up `POST 0 B null ms curl/7.68.0 http://example.a.run.app/` which is not really informative and I need to expand each log to see what it is.

My code is the following and I am using bazel to build the container:

```
import logging
import os

from flask import Flask, make_response
import google.cloud.logging

app = Flask(__name__)

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging()


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
  logging.warning('warning message')
  logging.info('info message')
  logging.error('error message')

  return make_response('OK', 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
```

[image]

other SO posts I am following to get log working:

[Log to Cloud Logging with correct severity from Cloud Run Job and package used in the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74302649/log-to-cloud-logging-with-correct-severity-from-cloud-run-job-and-package-used-i)

[Google Cloud Functions Python Logging issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147483/google-cloud-functions-python-logging-issue)

EDIT: Logs show up fine on "Logs Explorer" but not on "Logs" under "Cloud Run"

Comment: I have updated my answer below.please check

Comment: I can confirm the issue. It is very annoying problem that makes me think if I should switch from using google.cloud.logging to native logging with stderr as output. I would loose the severity-filter, but checking the logs would still be faster (especially with small apps)

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug raised for `display textPayload (when it's present) instead of a URL in the initial collapsed view of an entry in the legacy log viewers` at [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192479658). Which is still open, there is no update for a long time and the last update was to

> right-click on the textPayload field, you can select "Add field to
> summary line" and this will be put in the collapsed summary line.

you may consider adding your concern in that issue tracker or raise a [new issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/) by referencing that thread further progress can be tracked there.